# Sendkeys.Send() for right alt key? any alternatives?

Tags: c#, winforms, sendkeys, alt

I am working on a winform app for a touch screen monitor.
The app consists of a web browser and a on screen keyboard.
I have most everything I need, but the problem I am facing is that
there are two input languages, English and Korean.
Anyone familiar with using two languages can tell you that the right <kbd>alt</kbd> key
is used to go back and forth between languages.
I need to simulate this keystroke, but I can't find anything for it.

I have found ways to simulate left/right <kbd>shift</kbd> keys, and left/right <kbd>ctrl</kbd> keys.
But nothing for left/right <kbd>alt</kbd> keys.

Do I have any alternatives?

Comment: I use a combination of Left Alt / Left Shift for switching keyboards using the built-in Language Bar in Windows. Take a look at the settings dialog for the Language Bar. Maybe you can set the keyboard shortcut to something that suits you better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `keybd_event` with `RALT` keycode `VK_RMENU`. A complete list of keycodes are [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms927178.aspx)

You would have to [P/Invoke](http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.keybd_event) the keystroke like this:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)] 
static extern void keybd_event(byte bVk, byte bScan, int dwFlags, int dwExtraInfo);  

public const int KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY = 0x0001; //Key down flag 
public const int KEYEVENTF_KEYUP = 0x0002; //Key up flag 
public const int VK_RMENU = 0xA5;

keybd_event(VK_RMENU, 0, KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY, 0); 
keybd_event(VK_RMENU, 0, KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0);
```

Comment: There is no need to use P/Invoke and invent the wheel again! `Keys.RMenu` is equivalent to `VK_RMENU`.

Comment: I used what you gave me, and the extendedkey is working fine, but it seems like it's not releasing. if i type something and press backspace, it works more as an undo function.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to simulate Alt+Shift keystrokes for changing input language. You can use `InputLanguage` class in `System.Windows.Forms` namespace:

```
        var currentLang = InputLanguage.CurrentInputLanguage;
        var installedLangs = InputLanguage.InstalledInputLanguages;
        if (installedLangs.Count > 1)
            InputLanguage.CurrentInputLanguage =
                installedLangs[1 - installedLangs.IndexOf(currentLang)];
```

When you have exactly 2 input languages installed, this code fragments switches between those two. You get the idea. Right?

Comment: That's cool, I managed to miss that one. Although it seems it's part of the Winforms framework. There's probably an equivalent one for WPF.

Comment: I do, because the site forces korean input whether the user has korean as the active input

Answer (score 1):

You don't really want to find a way to send the Alt key, right? What you really want is to be able to change the input language. In that case, go straight to the source.

The Windows API has methods to change the current active keyboard layout. They're not part of the .NET Framework, but you can use P/Invoke to call them from C#.

The MSDN documentation for the ActivateKeyboardLayout is [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646289%28VS.85%29.aspx).

And the P/Invoke signatures can be found [here](http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32/ActivateKeyboardLayout.html).

Comment: `InputLanguage` class does what you are looking for. And it is available in .NET Framework!

Answer (score 1):

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.keys.aspx) gives the `RMenu` enum entry for right-alt.